# How do i create nameservers for vps?

Tags: networking, dns, vps

I have recently bought a VPS and a domain from 2 different sites. So with the VPS i got a IP address and supposedly 2 NS. But in my VPS nameservers ip addresses are

> 8.8.8.8 , 8.8.4.4.

I am assuming i have to create a nameserver in this scenario with NS1.domain.com and ns2.domain.com using vps ip address and register these 2 in domain's registrar. But my vps don't give me any interface to make nameservers and i assume i have to do this manually. I would be grateful if someone correct me if i understand it wrongly or if my understanding is correct then how to create 2 nameservers for my vps using terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4 are the nameservers that your Ubuntu installation in the VPS will use to resolve domains. These are not related to your domain name.

Your DNS registrar (like gandi.net) offers for free a DNS server that serves your domains and subdomains. You do not need to set that server in your VPS.